# Tree class in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to solve a problem regarding numbers saved in a tree structure.
[image]

I would like to create one class called Tree and another one called Element (in this case would be an Integer but it could be whatever) and make it the most adequate way based on C++ standards. It should be possible to add childs to a specific element in the tree and traceback the parent of each element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Element
{
public:
    Element() = delete;
    explicit Element(int value, Element* parent = nullptr):
            value_(value), parent_(parent), children_() {}
    int getValue() const { return value_; }
    Element* getParent() { return parent_; }
    // it will throw if idx out of bounds
    Element* getChild(size_t idx) { return children_.at(idx).get(); }


    size_t numChildren() const { return children_.size(); }
    Element* insertChild(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "new elem: " << value << std::endl;
        children_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Element>(value, this));
        return children_.back().get();
    }
    bool moveChildren2Parent()
    {
        if (isRoot()) return false;
        for (auto& c : children_)
        {
            // children change parent
            c->parent_ = parent_;
            parent_->children_.emplace_back(std::move(c));
        }
        children_.clear();
        return true;
    }
    bool removeChild(size_t idx)
    {
        if (children_.size() <= idx) return false;
        children_.erase(children_.begin()+idx);
        return true;
    }
    bool isRoot() { return parent_ == nullptr; }

private:
    int value_;
    Element* parent_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element> > children_;
};

void checkChilds(Element* element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < element->numChildren(); i++)
    {
        if (element->getChild(i)->numChildren() == 1)
        {
            element->getChild(i)->moveChildren2Parent();
            element->removeChild(i);
            i--;
        } else if (element->getChild(i)->numChildren() > 1)
        {
            checkChilds(element->getChild(i));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto root = std::make_shared<Element>(0);
    Element* _ = root->insertChild(1)->insertChild(3)->insertChild(5);
    Element* last_child = root->insertChild(2)->insertChild(4)->insertChild(7);
    last_child->getParent()->insertChild(6);

    for (int i=0;i<root->numChildren();i++)
    {
        if (root->getChild(i)->numChildren()==1)
        {
            root->getChild(i)->moveChildren2Parent();
            root->removeChild(i);
            i--;
        }
        else if (root->getChild(i)->numChildren()>1)
        {
            checkChilds(root->getChild(i));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My objective is to create a tree and after if each element just has one child remove that element while keeping the leaves.
My code works but I would like to know improvements to make it better looking based on C++ standards.

---

### EDIT

Thanks to the answer @pptaszni and after adapting it to my specific problem at hand this is the result. I think my implementation to go over all the elements checking if the number of childs they have is equal 1 and if so remove is not nicely written. Do you know how could I optimize it (the last for loop in main and function checkChilds)?

Comment: `Element(){}` is required from `getElement()` function, when you return as `m_elements[value]`, this will try to insert a default constructed object since it has no way to receive arguments, you can use `m_elements.at(value)` to access an already present element.

Answer (score 1):

is there any specific reason you need two different class for element and tree?
i suggest, have just one class which have one data member which will store a node value and two pointers to point at two different child objects.

following is the suggestion based on what i have have understood from your question.

```
class Node
{
    int value;
    Node* left_child = nullptr; 
    Node* right_child = nullptr;
    //methods for modifying tree.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: don't use [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), because it inserts default-constructed element if it doesn't exist in the map. You can use [at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) instead.

Then about your architecture: it doesn't look very good, because having a child, it's not obvious how to get parent, having a parent, it's not obvious how to get it's children, your `std::map` key is supposed to be unique and you also use it as a value for your `Elements`. I suggest to apply at least the following:

```
class Element
{
public:
  Element() = delete;
  explicit Element(int value, Element* parent = nullptr):
    value_(value), parent_(parent), left_child_(nullptr), right_child_(nullptr) {}
  int getValue() const { return value_; }
  Element* getParent() { return parent_; }
  Element* getLeftChild() { return left_child_.get(); }
  Element* getRightChild() { return right_child_.get(); }
  Element* insertLeftChild(int value)
  {
    if (left_child_)
    {
      std::cout << "already exists" << std::endl;
      return left_child_.get();  // already exists
    }
    std::cout << "new left elem: " << value << std::endl;
    left_child_ = std::make_unique<Element>(value, this);
    return left_child_.get();
  }
  bool isRoot() { return parent_ == nullptr; }

private:
  int value_;
  Element* parent_;
  std::unique_ptr<Element> left_child_;
  std::unique_ptr<Element> right_child_;
};

int main()
{
  auto root = std::make_shared<Element>(1);
  Element* last_child = root->insertLeftChild(2)->insertLeftChild(3)->insertLeftChild(4);
  std::cout << last_child->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getParent()->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getParent()->getParent()->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getParent()->getParent()->isRoot() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now you have the access to parent and children from every element and you can start building your tree. Then there are further concerns like `Element` comparison operator (if needed), only 2 children per node or maybe more, pointers invalidation on every tree modification etc. It is a big topic in general.

======= EDIT =========

To answer OP's concern about multiple children, and to provide an example of removing the node while preserving the leaves (children):

```
class Element
{
public:
  Element() = delete;
  explicit Element(int value, Element* parent = nullptr):
    value_(value), parent_(parent), children_() {}
  int getValue() const { return value_; }
  Element* getParent() { return parent_; }
  // it will throw if idx out of bounds
  Element* getChild(size_t idx) { return children_.at(idx).get(); }
  size_t numChildren() const { return children_.size(); }
  Element* insertChild(int value)
  {
    std::cout << "new elem: " << value << std::endl;
    children_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Element>(value, this));
    return children_.back().get();
  }
  bool moveChildren2Parent()
  {
    if (isRoot()) return false;
    for (auto& c : children_)
    {
      // children change parent
      c->parent_ = parent_;
      parent_->children_.emplace_back(std::move(c));
    }
    children_.clear();
    return true;
  }
  bool removeChild(size_t idx)
  {
    if (children_.size() <= idx) return false;
    children_.erase(children_.begin()+idx);
    return true;
  }
  bool isRoot() { return parent_ == nullptr; }

private:
  int value_;
  Element* parent_;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element> > children_;
};

int main()
{
  auto root = std::make_shared<Element>(1);
  Element* last_child = root->insertChild(2)->insertChild(3)->insertChild(4);
  last_child->getParent()->insertChild(5);
  std::cout << "numChildren: " << last_child->getParent()->numChildren() << std::endl;
  last_child->getParent()->moveChildren2Parent();
  std::cout << "numChildren: " << last_child->getParent()->numChildren() << std::endl;
  last_child->getParent()->removeChild(0);  // element with value 3 removed, it's children already transferred
  std::cout << last_child->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getParent()->getValue() << std::endl;
  std::cout << last_child->getParent()->getParent()->isRoot() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It is just one of many possibilities, particular implementation choice always depends on the system requirements.

Comment: But what if you can have N childs?

Comment: If you can have N children, then you need slightly different design. One possible approach is to have `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element> > children_` and `push_back` new children, whenever some method `addChild(int value)` is invoked. To get the child you might consider `Element* getChild(int idx) { return children_[idx]; }` or throw, if idx bigger than `children_.size()`; Alternatively you might have `std::set` of children if you want to compare them somehow and if they are unique.

Comment: @pptaszni Use `emplace_back` not `push_back` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @pptaszni one last question. The problem says that I have to remove all the nodes that have just one children (keeping the leaves though). How can you iterate over all the elements following your solution?

Comment: To iterate over elements is simple: `void visit(Element* el) { doSomething(el); for (auto child : el.getChildren()) visit(child); }` It's called [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). To remove the element, just go to it's parent and call `removeChild`, but there is a problem with "keeping the leaves". Leaves in the tree must have some parent, so you need to define what will happen with the orphaned children (by default, deleting parent automatically deletes all children). One possibility that I demonstrated is to `moveChildren2Parent`.

Comment: Ive edited my question with my implementation, even though I dont think is that well written

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your code there. The most glaring one I can see is that you are freely converting between `int` pairs and elements. Classes provide a way to strongly type our code, if `int`, `int` is mean to represent an `Element`, make it an `Element`!

The reason you have to declare a default constructor is because you have already declared a constructor. The compiler will only generate a default one for you if you havnt already declared one.

To make the compiler explcitly generate one for you use `default`. Like this:

```cpp
Element() = default;
```

To fix your weak typing issues you should use `Element` for `m_parent` and when adding an item to the `Tree`, if you need to do stuff like setting values of the parent then do that to the item you are passed to add. Like this

```
...
private:
Element m_parent;

...
void addElement(const Element& parent, int value)
    {
        Element elem = Element(value, parent);
        m_elements.insert(std::pair<int,Element>(value,elem));
    }
...
```

You also probably want to use a different container than `std::map`. If you want to have a concept of 'elements' then I would use `std::set`, store the element value or key as a member and overload the `<` operator (to allow sorting) to return the operation on the values/keys. `std::set` would allow you to search the tree (using a lambda with `find_if`) for keys *or* values as well as anything else (like parent matching).

This use of storing the parent as another `Element` also enables you to iterate back up the tree if you wanted too (independent of your container).